# How do I get my SQL to cascade only on certain conditions?

Tags: sql, oracle, alter-table, cascading-deletes

How do I get my SQL to cascade only on certain conditions?

I want the child tuple to be deleted on cascade when parent `column1` value is deleted only if `column2C` of CHILD is NOT equal to `NULL`.

Example :

```
create PARENT table(
    column1 varchar2(20) primary key, 
    column2 varchar2(20)
);

create CHILD table(
    column1C varchar2(20), 
    column2C varchar2(20) default NULL, 
    primary key(column1C,column2C)
);

alter table CHILD
    add constraint fk_const
    foreign key(column1C) references parent(column1)
    delete on cascade;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by means of triggers. more specifically you must write a trigger for the after delete event of table parent to check the condition and if it is true then delete the corresponding records in child table

Comment: aah. you beat me to it. Gave the same answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using triggers? It would be simpler, transparent and you can disable them if you dont need them without modifying the definition. Give a proper example if needed and try creating them.